# How to use the linenumbers mechanism from lineno twice in same document

Tags: line-numbering

I am using Gareth Walker's package [`convtran`](http://gareth-walker.staff.shef.ac.uk/convtran/) for typesetting conversation analysis examples.

That package makes use of the linenumbering mechanism from `lineno` to number lines in the examples. All fine. But now I ran into a problem because a journal `cls` file from a journal I'm submitting to also makes use of `lineno` for linenumbering (in my case the [MDPI LaTeX class](https://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex)) and that obviously clashes with the way linenumbers are set up for the examples (see the image).

[image]

Here's an MWE (requires [`convtran`](http://gareth-walker.staff.shef.ac.uk/convtran/)):

```
\documentclass{report}    
\usepackage{convtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\lipsum[4]

\begin{convtran}
    \turn{A:} Hello 
    \turn{B:} Hello 
\end{convtran}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to modify the way in which `convtran` uses the linenumbering mechanism in such a way that it doesn't interfere with linenumbering done via the `cls` file?

**EDIT:**
Essentially, I'd like to have complete linenumbers in the margins but still be able to use `convtran` with the specific linenumbers for transcripts (each starting from 1 without interfering with the linenumbers in the margins). This is how what I'm hoping to achieve should look:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proof-of-concept attempt. The key is to redefine `\makeLineNumber` so that it typesets line numbers twice. Current redefinition is (very) fragile to how `convtran` and `lineno` is used and/or configured.

```tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{convtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch} % for \xpatchcmd

% restore \linenumbersep changed by convtran
\setlength{\linenumbersep}{10pt}
\newcounter{convtran@start}

\makeatletter

\xpatchcmd\convtran
  {\linenumbers*}
  {%
    \ifLineNumbers
      \convtran@setMakeLineNumber
    \else
      \linenumbers*
      \convtran@restoreMakeLineNumber
    \fi
  }
  {}{\PatchFailed}

% 
\newcommand\convtran@setMakeLineNumber{%
  \let\makeLineNumber@orig=\makeLineNumber
  \setcounter{convtran@start}{\value{linenumber}}%
  \renewcommand\makeLineNumber{%
    \begingroup
      \setlinenoplace{-0.75cm}%
      \c@linenumber=\numexpr\c@linenumber-\c@convtran@start+1\relax
      \hbox to 0pt{\makeLineNumber@orig}% line number for convtran
    \endgroup
    \makeLineNumber@orig % normal line number
  }%
}

\newcommand\convtran@restoreMakeLineNumber{%
  \setlinenoplace{-0.75cm}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcommand\test{%
  \lipsum[4][1-4]
  
  \begin{convtran}
    \turn{A:} Hello 
    \turn{B:} Hello
  \end{convtran}
  
  \lipsum[4][1-4]
  \rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}\bigskip
}

\linenumbers
\test

\nolinenumbers
\test

\linenumbers[20]
\test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks very promising – but there's still one issue:  when I outcomment `\linenumbers` at `\begin{document}` then margin linenumbers still appear in the margin of the `convtran` lines :(

Comment: @jan Answer updated. With the help of `\ifLineNumbers`, now it should work.

Comment: It does :)  Thanks so much!   Fragile or not, it does the job.  I would hope the `convtran` maintainer would use this for creating linenumbers in the style itself  (as the way in which it uses the `linenumbers` mechanism currently doesn't seem to be the ideal way of doing things anyways ...)

Comment: Thanks. I have incorporated this code into the package. Since the package meets most of my needs I don't generally spend time on it, but I am well aware it could be improved. Any improvements gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

In the mentioned `convtran.sty`, the tag `\linenumbersep` controls the spacing of linenumbers, you can modify it what ever you like, and the modified `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{report}    
\usepackage{convtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\setlength\linenumbersep{20pt}
\linenumbers
\lipsum[4]

\begin{convtran}
    \turn{A:} Hello 
    \turn{B:} Hello 
\end{convtran}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.  The issue is that `\linenumbersep` controls the spacing globally.  What I'm hoping to achieve (and what I've now clarified in the question), is to have two independent sets of linenumbers on in the margins and one for the transcripts, each with independent parameters ...